# Saving the values in forms after leaving the page in reactjs

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, jsx

So I have a bunch of forms that the user can navigate back and forth from, but when he comes back the form should be as they left it, and all their values can be submitted at once.

I thought of keeping a large object, that temporarily stores the value for all the forms and is what is submitted by then end of it.
Whenever I return to the page, I just put that certain object in the value property.

The problem with this, is that once I return to the filled out form, I can't edit it anymore.

What can I do to make this happen? Also, I am willing to change it completely if there is a whole better way to do this.

Here is some relevant code with some comments explaining things:

```
// form3 only has to text fields, and form4 only has a file entry, 
//which is why they aren't objects
//form1 and form2 on the other hand are huge and generate dynamically (I get 
//all their fields through a get request and don't necessarily know 
//how many there will be 
export var formDataObject = {
    form1:{},
    form2:{},
    form3:{
        field1:"",
        field2:""
    },
    form4:""
};

// for the next part I'll use form3 as an example since it is simple:
//The Form3 component is just a simple text input, I include the code 
//of that too in case it's needed
export default class FullForm3 extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            initial_field1: formDataObject.form3.field1,
            initial_field2: formDataObject.form3.field2
        }
    }

    render(){
        var field1Value, field2Value;
        if (this.state.initial_field1.length>0)
            field1Value = formDataObject.form3.field1;
        if (this.state.initial_field2.length>0)
            field2Value = formDataObject.form3.field2;
        return (
            <div>
                <Panel>
                    <Form3 controlId="field1Id" label={field1Label}
                          value={field1Value}/>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <Form3 controlId="field2Id" label={field2Label}
                          value={field2Value}/>

            </div>

            );
        }
}

class Form3 extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: formDataObject.form3,
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        const value = Object.assign({}, this.state.value);
        value[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ value });
        formDataObject.form3= this.state.value;
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        //things for submit (not important)
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Form inline onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <ControlLabel>{this.props.label}</ControlLabel>
                    <FormControl
                        type='text' label='Text'
                        value={this.props.value} onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                </FormGroup>

            </Form>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're issue is that you're doing some things in React, and some things not in React (the global object). Try splitting your components into multiple files, and only pass in data to them via props. What you'll need is a parent component above all the forms that keeps the state for all the forms (similar to your global object), and has an onchange handler that it passes down to the forms to change its own state. I recommend taking a look at: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: @MatthewHerbst read the tutorial and re-created it. Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I did it in a few steps:

1. Create controlled forms/inputs
2. OnInputChange save the formData for later use inside a callback from setState() (I used localStorage)
3. Get saved data in constructor(more readable in my example)/componentWillMount and setState of inputs to saved values
4. Now you can edit these inputs after refresh

Here you have full component with 2 inputs:

```
class SimpleInputs extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    if(localStorage.getItem('formData')) {
      this.state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formData')); //in this case the state is just for input values
    } else {
      this.state = {
        value1: '',
        value2: ''
      }
    }

    this.handleInput1Change = this.handleInput1Change.bind(this);
    this.handleInput2Change = this.handleInput2Change.bind(this);
  }

  handleInput1Change(event) {
    this.setState({ value1: event.target.value }, () => {
      localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(this.state)); 
    });
  }
  handleInput2Change(event) {
    this.setState({ value2: event.target.value }, () => {
      localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(this.state));
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <form>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value1} onChange={this.handleInput1Change}/>
        <label>Phone number</label>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value2} onChange={this.handleInput2Change}/>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that gave me the same problem I was having before =/ It may save the values, but doesn't let me add anything after that. Unless I am doing something wrong...